# How to create an access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-authentication

I am a bit confused about the facebook graph api and access tokens.

I have created a facebook user and a facebook page. Now I want to write an application that lets the user post a message on the pages wall/feed. As far as I understand it right now I need an access token of the user to post a message to the pages wall. To create that I need an app id and app secret. But there is no app, there is just the page and the feed. Do I have to create an app? And how would I connect the app to the page without creating a new tab on that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do **anything** whilst acting as a user, you're going to need an App and the correct permissions from the User. Read more about Authentication [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: Thank you. I read the manual. But I think I do understand it now. I don't need permission to write a post on the wall by the page because everybody is permitted to write on a wall, right? But my PHP script needs to tell facebook that it is allowed to act as user XYC and therefore the PHP script has to be represented by a facebook app and the user has to give the permissions to that app to write postings etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it stofl. The permission isn't to write on the page, it's permission for your app to write anything whilst acting as a user.